# Spring Integrations Flow: Error Handling Design

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Looking for advice on error handling using spring IntegrationFlows. I have a set up with many flows with a mixture of routing, transformations and channels this is fully working.

Currently for error handling I catch all checked expectations that a given `.handle(..)` may throw and re-throw them as a Runtime exception. This causes the exception to hit my error channel, where I deal with the problem. I am looking to see if this is how the use of channels and Integrations flows was designed.

```
  return IntegrationFlows.from("test")
     .handle(X.class, (p, h) -> process(p))
     .handle(More::EndPorcess)
     .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what is the question though?

It isn't regular Java, so there is something in between operators. It is message channel. And that is really designed to end up in the `errorChannel` if there is no ability to bubble exception as a StackTrace: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler